# Using database generated GUID and datetime with EF4

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I have a simple table with an ID (a `uniqueidentifier`), a `datetime`, and a value.

I'd like to use `getdate()` on the database for the record insertion time and `newid()` for the id. How do I configure entity framework to do this? When I try to assign the id on the DB I get:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Random'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Random'. The duplicate key value is (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000).
```

Answer (score 22):

if you are using code first. Please add the following to your guid.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid guId { get; set; }
```

This will enable sql server side guid generation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that this requires a reference to the namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema`

Comment: I've been told that this would mean that you can't set the Guid manually if `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` is set. This might be a problem if you have to sync databases.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to this since @lunateck answer helped me. The other way (if you are using Database First) is to:

1. Open your `edmx` file.
2. Right click -> Model Browser
3. Right click the Guid column -> Properties -> change the `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `Identity`.

Comment: Booya - that was the one.